# What does sched_yield do in this case?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64

If I have a process whose all threads are running on different cores, what will `sched_yield` do in that case? Get relinquished and immediately issued again? Because what I see is that `sched_yield` does not cause the thread calling it, wait any cycles at all, it seems that the call is not even going to the kernel.

Answer (score 4):

As far as the linux kernel is concern, one core is one CPU, so `sched_yield` would causes the calling thread to relinquish the CPU but if the thread is the only one in the queue, it won't wait any cycle.

So **yes** in your case **`sched_yield` would immediatly return immediatly** if there are no thread waiting on the current core.

Note that `sched_yield` is **not** designed to control how threads are run on multiple CPU.

Comment: sched_yield **is** a system call, the C implementation does nothing more than something like `_syscall0(int, sched_yield)`

Answer (score 3):

The man page says:

> If the calling thread is the only thread in the highest priority
>   list at that time, it will continue to run after a call to sched_yield().

So if there's nothing more important to run, the function will basically do nothing.

Comment: "So if there's nothing more important to run, the function will basically do nothing." But it will do a system call (and switching from user space to kernel) nevertheless, or not even?

Comment: Yes it would still do a system call, check the waiting list  of the CPU scheduler and return without waiting if there are no other waiting threads.

Comment: Well I don't have a Linux to test on right now, so maybe you can make a program that just calls sched_yield in a loop and profile it?